# Vim autoindent and xml self-closing

Tags: indentation, filetype-xml

(previously posted on https://stackoverflow.com/q/62000643/3206025 before I get that there is a Vi's SE)

Here my vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent 
set tabstop=2 
set shiftwidth=2 
set softtabstop=2
```

And that all.

Let suppose I start a new xml file.

WHen a use normal tag, autoindent work well

```
<div>
  <p> 
     Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

But if I insert autoclosing tags, autoindnet don't recognize the autoclosing feature,and I get something like this.

```
<div>
  <p> 
     Some text<lb />
        Some text<lb />
             Some text<lb />
  </p>
</div>
```

I use vim 8.1.2269. I tried with nvim 0.4.3 > same problem. WHat is strange is that in the past (before my new fresh installation of Ubuntu), I didn't get any problem...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You can try using `gq` since the xml filetype sets `formatexpr`, but I didn't see anywhere (after a quick peek) that the scripts handle self-closing tags.

Comment: I believe @ChristianBrabandt is the maintainer of XML indentation in Vim, so maybe he might know why it seems to handle this case incorrectly?

Comment: thanks for you answer. I will post on github repository.

Answer (score 1):

Thats was a bug. Thanks to @ChristianBrabandt who solved it very quickly.

https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/issues/25